# Is it possible to change the filename for server response?

Tags: angular, filepond

I want to change the filename for the new name that my backend sends to me,is it possible?

here my filepond options and im using angular:

```
this.pondOptions = {
            allowMultiple: this.multiple,
            labelIdle: 'Arraste seus arquivos<br>ou<br><span class="filepond--label-action">Clique aqui</span> para selecionar',
            allowReorder: true,
            maxFiles: this.maxFiles,
            acceptedFileTypes: ['image/*'],
            instantUpload: true,
            dropValidation: true,
            styleButtonRemoveItemPosition: 'right',
            imageResizeMode: 'contain',
            styleItemPanelAspectRatio: '0.75',
            itemInsertLocation: 'after',
            server: {
                process: {
                    url: this.url
                },
                load: (source, load, error, progress, abort, headers) => {
                    var myRequest = new Request(source);
                    fetch(myRequest).then(response => {
                        response.blob().then(myBlob => {
                            load(myBlob)
                        });
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.log('ERROR: ', error)
                    });
                },
            },

        };
    }
```

i tried to use the fileRenamePlugin with a promise but didnt work